# SQL: Select all items and add info from left join where condition is met

Tags: join, select

**Background**

I am creating a news site. Table NEWS has all news with unique ID news_uid.

```
TABLE NEWS
--------------
news_uid | ...
```

If a user has read a certain news, that info gets stored in table NEWSREAD:

```
TABLE NEWSREAD
--------------
user_uid | news_uid | news_read
-------------------------------
A        | N1       | 1
A        | N2       | 1
B        | N3       | 1
```

So here user A has read News 1 and 2 and user B has read N3.

**Question**

I am trying to create a SQL query that

- Selects all news from the news table
- And tells me for a given user, which news have been read

Output:

```
news_uid | news read by user A
------------------------------
N1       | 1
N2       | 1
N3       | 0 (or NULL)
```

I have gotten so far, but this does not show N3 in the results.

```
SELECT NEWS.news_uid, NEWSREAD.news_read FROM NEWS 
LEFT JOIN NEWSREAD ON NEWS.uid = NEWSREAD.news_uid 
WHERE NEWSREAD.user_uid = 'A' or NEWSREAD.user_uid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NEWS.news_uid, NEWSREAD.news_read 
FROM NEWS 
LEFT JOIN NEWSREAD ON NEWS.uid = NEWSREAD.news_uid 
                  AND NEWSREAD.user_uid = 'A'
```